# Require handling component EventEmitter @output

Tags: angular

`selector: 'element[title]'`

requires `<element title="value" ></element>` for the component to be display
You will get an error if you don't use the require property like `<element title="value" ></element>`

How can I do this for EventEmitter output?

```
@Output() customEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>()
this.customEvent.next()
```

```html
<element title="value" (customEvent)="handleCustomEvent()"></element>
```

Doesn't work `selector: 'element[title](customEvent)'`

Ultimately, I just want my code to tell me something is wrong before I run my code.

Comment: It's ultimately just another property, so `element[title][customEvent]` should work.

Comment: Blackhole, I wish you added your commend has an answer so I can officially accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is what I was looking for, Thank you Backhole.

It's ultimately just another property, so element[title][customEvent] should work.
– [Blackhole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057033/blackhole)

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit `@Output` variable like below in element component

```
this.customEvent.emit(true);
```

If this is not you are looking for, feel free to modify below Stackblitz example

**Stackblitz**: https://angular-ivy-wjru8q.stackblitz.io

Comment: That is what I have. The customEvent is optional. If you handle it or not our code doesn't say anything unlike having a require property.

Comment: Blackhole had it right. I can add it has a required property on the selector, and it works.